# Last occurance of an item that is not a string in a list - Python

Tags: python, list, indexing, ironpython

I have list of lists of numbers e.g.

```
[[0,0,0,0,0], [1,1,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0], [1,1,1,1,0]]
```

I would like to find the index of the last 1 in each list. The left most number is index 0.

The items in the list are not strings so I can't use "`.rindex`" function.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: `[0,0,0,0,0]` this has no `1` in it what would be the output for this

Comment: I would just need a place holder -1 or even could be a string "null".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` to get every index of `1` and extract the last element.

```
[[idx for idx,v in enumerate(i) if v==1][-1] if 1 in i else -1 for i in lst]
# [-1, 1, 0, -1, 3]
```

Or use `str.rfind` which wouldn't raise error when an element is not found it returns `-1`.

```
 [''.join(map(str,i)).rfind('1') for i in lst]
# [-1, 1, 0, -1, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the first solution you suggested.

Comment: @sjmurphy84 Glad to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

We can reverse the list (`list[::-1]) and then use the index function to find its location.

Finally, the indexes need to be adjusted using the list length (correcting for index numbers in python starting at 0.

```py
data = [[0,0,0,0,0], [1,1,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0], [1,1,1,1,0]]

# loop through all values (the lists) in data and select their last element.

last_list = [len(i) - i[::-1].index(1) - 1  if (1 in i) else None for i in data]
```